# R: Find function minimum with genetic programming

Tags: r, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming

I am currently using [RGP](https://rsymbolic.org/projects/rgp/) as a genetic programming library. If anyone has an idea for another library  (better documentation, more active development, etc.) I would like to hear your suggestions.

The question is rather simple: given a function with n parameters in R, how can i find the global minimum using genetic programming. I tried modifying one of the [example programs](https://rsymbolic.org/projects/rgp/wiki/Getting_Started)  but it seems this example uses linear regression which I don't think is appropriate in my situation.

Does anyone have any example code i could use?

Comment: Problems like global minimum usually require something like simulated annealing.

Comment: I use Differential Evolution via the [DEoptim package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DEoptim/index.html).

Comment: the DEoptim package sounds promising. I will look into it.

Comment: You might check out the [rgenoud](http://sekhon.berkeley.edu/rgenoud/) package.

Answer (score 3):

I can recommend to use [HeuristicLab](http://dev.heuristiclab.com). There are some algorithms implemented: Genetic Algorithm, Evolution Strategy, Simulated Annealing, Particle Swarm Optimization, and more which might be interesting if you're looking into the minimization of real-valued functions. The software is implemented in C# and runs on Windows. It offers a GUI where you can optimize several provided test functions (Rosenbrock, Schaffer, Ackley, etc.). There's also a very good implementation of genetic programming (GP) available, but from my impression you don't need GP. In genetic programming you evolve a function given the output data of an unknown function. I think in your case the function is known and you need to find those parameters that minimize the function's output.

The latest major version of the software was released to the public in 2010 and has since been further developed in several minor releases. We now have a release about two times a year. There's a google group where you can ask for help which is getting more and more active and there are some video tutorials that show the functionality. Check out the [tour video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NGnDC14Pfic) on youtube which gives an overview of the features in less than 3 minutes. The research group around Prof. Affenzeller - a researcher in the field of Metaheuristics - has developed this software and is situated in Austria. I'm part of this group also.

Check out the [howtos](http://dev.heuristiclab.com/howtos) how you can implement your function in the GUI or, if you know C#, how you can implement your problem as a plugin.

Comment: thanks for your answer. HeuristicLab looks nice, although I was specifically asking for R packages. So, it's not suitable for this project but I will definately Bookmark it for potential later use.

Comment: HeuristicLab (C#, GPL) looks nice. Very similar to what we build in [Drools Planner](http://www.jboss.org/drools/drools-planner) (java, ASL).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a **genetic algorithm** instead of GP to find the minimum of a function with n variables.

Basically what you do is:

- assign initial values
- generate initial population of n chromosomes
- While (true)

  - evaluate fitness f(x, y) for each chromosome

    - if we reach a satisfactory solution of f(x, y) → Exit the loop
  - create the selection scheme (tournament selection)
  - select chromosomes (selection):

    - elitism
    - crossover
  - create mutations
  - alter duplicated chromosomes
  - replace the original population of chromosomes
- end While